# Retrieving data from QR Code and storing it into an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, qr-code

```
var test = new Array("abc","def","ghi");
```

This array is the input data for the QR Code.

```
function (result) {
    alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
    }
```

The above code is to retrieve `result` from QR code.

However, after retrieving the result from QR code, the result is currently is just one string of text.

```
"abc, def, ghi"
```

Is there any way I can store it into an Array again?

Comment: Once you have the string, it really doesn't matter if it came from user input, a QR code or whatnot.  A good question would include an example of the input you have (which is very likely to be a string).  If you have the string and you want to split it, there are a good number of questions on how to  `split` a string.  (hint, hint).

Comment: The `+` operator will automatically convert to a string (it can be somewhat derpy, though, so watch out). As for splitting by a comma in your string, try `result.text.split(",")`

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher improved the way of asking. Thank you!

Comment: @SpeedyNinja would have a try on that, thank you!

Comment: Are you using a specific library? there may be another property to the result that will get you the array that you need, instead of the text property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, the `String.prototype.split` will do what you are asking for:

```js
// A string with a comma and a space:
var str1 = "abc, def, ghi";
var array = str1.split(", ");
console.log(array);

// A string with just commas:

var str2 = "abc,def,ghi";
var array = str2.split(",");
console.log(array);
```